# Is "website-design" a useful tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Our most common tag is [website-design](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/website-design).  Without reading the tag's wiki, it seems like most questions on this site are about "web-design," which means that many users may begin typing "web" and then select that tag if their project has anything to do with the web.

The current wiki for the tag limits that scope somewhat to decisions that impact the website as a whole

> website design involves the structure of the website including the information architecture, layout, content, and the conceptual design with branding.

Most of these terms are already tags of their own, each with several questions.

[information-architecture](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/information-architecture) × 120 
 [layout](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/layout) × 313 
 [content](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/content) × 54 
 [branding](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/branding) × 12

**Given that even the subtags that make up the categories of the [website-design](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/website-design) tag have hundreds of questions, do we really need a tag for [website-design](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/website-design)?**

- If so, what distinguishes it from the other tags?  Should its meaning be changed to only deal with the "conceptual design" of the site (the only part of the tag's wiki that doesn't currently have a tag of its own)?
- If not, is there consensus that it should be removed?

Comment: I'm not a fan of it (worse is GUI design) but it does make it clear when the context is the web, which can be relevant

Comment: @BenBrocka I tend to view tags as existing to help people find information rather than as serving to explain the context of a question.  There's no limit on the body text for people to explain as much context as they want, but they can only use five tags to make the question findable.